# Orientdb Insertion Using Java

Tags: java, orientdb

I want to insert some vertices and edges into a OrientDB using Java. 
How would I do that?
Is there a restful api call for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Java, the easiest way is using the native driver:

```
 OrientGraph g = new OrientGraph("remote:localhost/yourDb");
 Vertex v1 = g.addVertex("class:YourClass");
 v1.setProperty("name", "foo");
 v1.setProperty("surname", "bar");
 Vertex v2 = g.addVertex("class:YourClass");
 v1.addEdge("YourEdgeClass", v2)
 g.shutdown();
```

For massive insert, you can also use OGraphBatchInsert (with some limitations).

Of course there is also a REST API, take a look at this http://orientdb.com/docs/last/OrientDB-REST.html

Comment: How to insert using  vertex uisng rest api